# Prove that a set system is a $\sigma$-Algebra

Tags: measure-theory

We have two (non-empty) sets $\mathcal X$ and $\mathcal Y$, and two (non-empty) set systems $\mathscr E \subset \mathcal P(\mathcal X)$ and $\mathscr F\subset \mathcal P(\mathcal Y)$.

I need to prove that $\Omega = \{ A \in \mathcal P(\mathcal X): A \times F \in \sigma(\mathscr E \times \mathscr F) \}$ for a $F \in \mathscr F$ is a $\sigma \text{-Algebra}$.

I see why $\emptyset \in \Omega$ and why $\Omega$ is closed under countable unification, but I do not see why from $A \in \Omega$ it should follow that $A^c \in \Omega$.

Comment: what's set systems? can you write the definition?

Comment: Nothing more than this $\mathscr E \subset \mathcal P(\mathcal X)$, just a subset of the power set.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have a (possible) counterexample

$\mathcal{X} = \{1,2\}$
$\mathcal{Y} = \{3,4\}$

Take $\mathscr{E} =\{ \{1\}\}$ and $\mathscr{F}=\{\{3\}\}$, then

$\sigma(\mathscr{E}\times \mathscr{F})=\{\emptyset,\{(1,3)\},\{(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)\},\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}\}$

Now, the set $\{1\}\in \Omega$ because $\{1\}\times\{3\} = \{(1,3)\}$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra, but the set $\{2\} = \{1\}^c$ is not in $\Omega$ (because $\{(2,3)\}$ is not in the $\sigma$-algebra).

Comment: Should I read $\mathscr E = \{\{1\}\}$ (analogous correction for  $\mathscr F$)?  $\mathscr E$ and $\mathscr F$ are sets of subsets.

Comment: But apart from this seems to be indeed a counterexample.

Comment: Yeah corrected. I believe the statement would be true if you would replace $\sigma(\mathscr{E}\times \mathscr{F})$ with $\sigma(\mathscr{E}\times \mathscr{F})\cup\sigma(\mathscr {E}^c \times \mathscr{F}^c)$ in the definition of $\sigma$.